# Replace existing and add new entries in std::map

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, stdmap

Consider following snippet:

```
MapT map;

map["A"] = 1;
map["B"] = 2;
map["C"] = 3;
map["D"] = 4;
map["E"] = 5;

MapT mapSecond;

mapSecond["A"] = 10;
mapSecond["B"] = 20;
mapSecond["C"] = 30;
mapSecond["X"] = 4;
mapSecond["Y"] = 5;

MapT::const_iterator itSecond = mapSecond.begin();
MapT::iterator it = map.begin();

for (; itSecond != mapSecond.end(); ++itSecond)
{
    std::pair<MapT::iterator, bool> pair = map.insert(std::make_pair(itSecond->first, itSecond->second));
    if (!pair.second)
    {
        pair.first->second = itSecond->second;
    }
}

for (; it != map.end(); ++it)
{
    std::cout << it->first << " " << it->second << std::endl;
}
```

I assume using the returned iterator from insert is the most efficient version.

However at first, I did just thought assigning the iterators only works fine (note I am not dereferencing the iterator anymore here).

1.)

```
// assigning the dereferenced iterator (i.e.: the underlying std::pair)
// resulting in no match for binary '=' operator for const std::string
*pair->first = *itsecond;
```

I know its obsolete as I already matched the key and only care about the value. This error occurs only because of the key being a const std::string If I am not completely out of my mind :D

2.)

```
// assigning the iterator itself
// does not compile as long as itSecond is of type const_iterator ?
// does nothing in case itSecond is of type iterator
pair.first = itSecond;
```

This is the thing I actually don't understand. How is the assignment of an iterator in a std::map supposed to behave? 
Although I do program C++ for a few years already, I never encountered a scenario where I did so for any container. I have not found a lot of information about assigning iterators in general during a bit of research.

And finally would there be an even more elegant way of doing what I want to achieve (using C++11 features, maybe C++14)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why make it so complicated? Why not simply

```
map[itSecond->first] = itSecond->second;
```

If they key exists, the data will be changed. If the key doesn't exist, then the pair will be inserted.

---

Also don't forget that the `value_type` of [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) (and [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) for that matter) is `std::pair<const Key, T>`.

As the key is *constant* you can't simply assign or copy iterators, you can only assign or copy the value.

Comment: Thanks! I still left the code as it is but from some reason I had in mind that operator[] does not change the value, its clear however it does by the looking at the declaration returning a T&.

Yeah and the value_type is std::pair<const Key, T> as I already figured out myself so the key cannot be changed ofc.

Comment: This requires that the `second` class has a default constructor - which might not be the case.

Comment: When the default allocator is used, the mapped type must be _DefaultConstructible_ - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at . How would `operator[]` be able to return a blank reference otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

To answer the first question

> How is the assignment of an iterator in a std::map supposed to behave?

:

[`MapT::Iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) satisfies [`BidirectionalIterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator), which satisfies [`ForwardIterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ForwardIterator), which satisfies [`Iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Iterator).

An `Iterator` is [`CopyAssignable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/CopyAssignable).

So the assignment `t = v;` will make

> - The value of `t` is equivalent to the value of `v`.
> - The value of `v` is unchanged.

In this case substitute `t` with `pair.first`, and `v` with `itSecond`. Note that the map is not changed with this.

(imagine pointers. Of course assigning pointers won't modify contents they point to)

Comment: (meta-commentary: it's very simple. Don't over-complexify it.)

Comment: (for the second question see [this another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51079331/5267751). It's probably good enough already, I don't need to repeat it)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming C++17 is okay, you can use merge: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/merge

But it doesn't overwrite the data, so you'd have to merge the first into the second.